# Using GDI+ in Delphi XE

Tags: delphi, gdi+, delphi-xe, delphi-xe2

The following works in Delphi XE2 but throws an access violation in Delphi XE:

```
uses
  GDIPAPI, GDIPOBJ;
...
TGPImage.Create (TStreamAdapter.Create (MemStream));   // throws AV
```

How can I use GDI+ in Delphi XE?

Comment: Try to use tmp variable, ie `SA := TStreamAdapter.Create(MemStream); TGPImage.Create(SA);`, sometimes this makes difference with some obscure compiler bug...

Comment: It works under Embarcadero® Delphi® XE Version 15.0.3953.35171

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the GDI+ units from [Progdigy](http://www.progdigy.com/?page_id=7) and renaming them to avoid conflicts with the ones used in the TeeCharts package solves the issue. XE does not come with sources for these units (XE2 does), so I'm not sure why it failed.

Comment: You mean to say that problem was due to namespace?

Comment: I believe it's due to an out of date binary DCU shipped with XE, but I'm not certain.  Or Smasher might have had some old versions of GDI+ units in his library path.